# How to use JS functions from an EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I was wondering how I would do it; use a function written in a external javascript file and then use it in `ejs`.

Here's the code;

```
 <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//gitcdn.link/repo/wintercounter/Protip/master/protip.min.js"></script>
    <script src='/javascripts/index.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//gitcdn.link/repo/wintercounter/Protip/master/protip.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <% include header %>   

    <section class='header-placeholder'></section>

    <section class='game'>
      <% items.forEach(function(item){ %>

        <% hi(); %>

      <% }); %>
    </section>

    <% include footer %>   
  </body>
```

I'm trying to call the function `hi()` which is written in `index.js` like so;

```
function hi(){
  console.log('hello');
}
```

is there any way I can access this function, or could I somehow have the function in ejs and access it from js?

Comment: You cannot do that and likely have XY problem. EJS file contains client-side scripts. And you want to evaluate them on server side. Consider re-asking the question with actual problem you're trying to solve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it . If you want to execute `hi` on server side, why did you define it in client side script then? I guess this isn't just about to say 'hi'.

Comment: @estus well the hi function is actually just a function that converts an object into a html string - for ease. I guess this ain't possible and I'll just have to copy pasta my code everywhere.

Comment: Yes, a simple solution is to copy and paste. In more complex setup you could place common code into common file and include it in both server and client side. This presumes that you use modules and bundling (Webpack, etc) for client-side app. You could also place common code into UMD module and load it in both and server side.